How to prove `A =~ Star re -> B =~ Star re -> A ++ B =~ Star re.` in Coq
I need to prove
A =~ Star re ->
  B =~ Star re ->
  A ++ B =~ Star re.

in order to prove Pumping Lemma. These are the available match rules:
Inductive exp_match {T} : list T -> reg_exp T -> Prop :=
  | MEmpty : [] =~ EmptyStr
  | MChar x : [x] =~ (Char x)
  | MApp s1 re1 s2 re2
             (H1 : s1 =~ re1)
             (H2 : s2 =~ re2)
           : (s1 ++ s2) =~ (App re1 re2)
  | MUnionL s1 re1 re2
                (H1 : s1 =~ re1)
              : s1 =~ (Union re1 re2)
  | MUnionR re1 s2 re2
                (H2 : s2 =~ re2)
              : s2 =~ (Union re1 re2)
  | MStar0 re : [] =~ (Star re)
  | MStarApp s1 s2 re
                 (H1 : s1 =~ re)
                 (H2 : s2 =~ (Star re))
               : (s1 ++ s2) =~ (Star re)

  where "s =~ re" := (exp_match s re).

I've tried inversion on the fact that A =~ Star re, but I recursively need to use the fact I'm trying to prove in order to be able to prove the goal.
Any help would be grat.

Indeed you should use induction. This is the same idea as concatenating lists, where MStar0 is nil and MStarApp is cons.

@NaïmFavier should I use induction on the definition of A and B? Because doing inversion on "A =~ Star re" lead to recursively seeing the goal.

Or maybe we should do induction on the goal as a whole? In that case can we just say "induction"?

You need induction and the remember tactic: https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/lf-current/IndProp.html#lab258

@JulioDiEgidio Thanks a lot! I was able to complete my proof for pumping lemma by your help. Thanks again!

Please publish your answer, and mark it as solved (if this is not an exercise from a book that requests answers to remain hidden).
